# Problem updating vector using for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run code which calculates the number of home goals each team in the Premier League scored last season. For some reason when I run the following for loop the vector OVHG's values don't change.

```
install.packages("Hash")
library(hash)

fantasyData <- read.csv("PremierData.csv")
attach(fantasyData)
head(fantasyData)

teams = c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Leicester", "Liverpool",
"Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Sheffield Wed", "Southampton", "Tottenham", "Watford", "West Ham", "Wolves")

values = seq(1, 20)
teamDict <- hash(teams, values)

OVHG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0)

for (team in teams) {
  for (i in 1:length(HomeTeam)) {
    if (HomeTeam[i] == team) {
      OVHG[teamDict$team] <- OVHG[teamDict$team] + FTHG[i]
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error message but the values of OVHG remain unchanged.

> OVHG
>    [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: IMHO here `attach()` causes the problem. `fortunes::fortune(379)`. You can use vector operations. `B <- BOD;
attach(B);
demand[3] <- 999;
detach(B);
B`

Comment: Is it `teamDict$team` in your loop or `teamDict[,team]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use vector operation for `i` and then indexing with a logical vector (`i`):

```
# install.packages("hash")
library("hash")

### data from https://datahub.io/sports-data/english-premier-league
fantasyData <- read.csv("https://datahub.io/sports-data/english-premier-league/r/season-1819.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Teams <- data.frame(teams = sort(unique(fantasyData$HomeTeam)), OVHG = 0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   

values = seq(1, 20)
teamDict <- hash(Teams$teams, values)

for (team in Teams$teams) {
  i <- (fantasyData$HomeTeam == team)
  Teams$OVHG[teamDict[[team]]] <- Teams$OVHG[teamDict[[team]]] + sum(fantasyData$FTHG[i])
}

Teams
```

Using `attach()` is often a bad idea; here is a short example of one attach-problem:

```
B <- BOD;
attach(B);
demand[3] <- 999;
demand;
detach(B);
B
```

Also read `fortunes::fortune(379)`

---

without `hash` you can do:

```
fantasyData <- read.csv("https://datahub.io/sports-data/english-premier-league/r/season-1819.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Teams <- data.frame(teams = sort(unique(fantasyData$HomeTeam)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ovhg <- function(team) sum(fantasyData$FTHG[fantasyData$HomeTeam == team])
Teams$OVHG <- sapply(Teams$teams, ovhg)

Teams
```

Comment: This is still giving me 0's just in a data frame now. I am trying to get the number of home goals scored by each team last season. This is a link to the dataset I used:  https://datahub.io/sports-data/english-premier-league

Comment: `teamDict` is a S4-object. I am not familiar with S4-objects and also not with the package `hash`. The error is in `teamDict$team`, see: `te <- "Arsenal";
teamDict$te;
teamDict[te];
getElement(teamDict, te)`; .... now I got it ...: edit follows